# WebView Content Dissappears When Navigating From It

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to set up a two screens app with navigation between them.
On screen 1 I have a WebView and a button that navigates to screen 2.
On screen 2 I have a button that navigates back to screen 1.
Whenever I navigate form 1 to 2, the content of the WebView disappears as soon as I tap the button.

```
struct PDFWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var navigateToScreen2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { _ in
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    PDFWebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf")!)
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: Screen2View(), isActive: $navigateToScreen2) {
                        Button("Go to 2") {
                            navigateToScreen2 = true
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .navigationBarTitle("Screen 1")
                .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Screen2View: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Go to 1") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.black)
        .navigationBarTitle("Screen 2", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Why is the content of the web view disappearing whenever I navigate to screen 2? how can I keep the content in the same state?

Comment: Move what you have in the update method to the make method

Comment: @loremipsum that doesn't work unfortunately